# Can't finish building kernel modules for Android

Tags: android, module, compilation, kernel

I'm trying to build a kernel module for Android, using the 2.6.32 kernel (a PL2303 usb-serial converter module, to be more exact), but for some reason I can't get to actually build the modules.

This is the code I run before compiling the modules:

```
export PATH=~/android-ndk-r5/toolchains/arm-eabi-4.4.0/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/:$PATH
make menuconfig ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-eabi- -j4
```

After configuring everything to match the tablet's kernel version, I run

```
make modules ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-eabi- -j4
```

And this is the makefile located on drivers/usb/serial (there are also several other lines like the last one for all the other drivers located on the folder, this is only the one I'm working with)

```
obj-$(CONFIG_USB_SERIAL)            += usbserial.o

usbserial-obj-$(CONFIG_USB_SERIAL_CONSOLE)  += console.o
usbserial-obj-$(CONFIG_USB_EZUSB)       += ezusb.o

usbserial-objs := usb-serial.o generic.o bus.o $(usbserial-obj-y)

obj-$(CONFIG_USB_SERIAL_PL2303)     += pl2303.o
```

But this only creates the .o files, and stops without building the actual .ko files. Any idea of what is causing this?

Comment: What's in your makefile?

Comment: use obj-m option in makefile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**obj-m :=** usbserial.o  tell it to make usbserial.ko

Please check the *Makefile* in [this](http://blog.csdn.net/yming0221/article/details/7194988), it may helps.